# Why does the gap between my cards not work

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Im new to wordpress so bear with me here. I have two cards which look fine on vscode but in wordpress the gap between the 2 is not right, the rest of the css is working fine though.

Im using kadence theme, and simple css plugin.
Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Card Effect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/95a02bd20d.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="face face1">
      <div class="content">
        <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
        <h3 style="font-family:Didot, serif; ">PHOTOGRAPHIE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="face face2">
      <div class="content">
        <p style="font-family:Didot, serif; "> Chaque cliché devient une pièce maîtresse de votre stratégie</p>
        <a href="#" type="button">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="face face1">
      <div class="content">
        <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
        <h3 style="font-family:Didot, serif; ">VIDEOGRAPHY</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="face face2">
      <div class="content">
        <p style="font-family:Didot, serif; ">Propulsez votre marque et stimuler l'engagement .</p>
        <a href="#" type="button">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And Here is my CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #444;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px; /* Adjust the maximum width as per your preference */
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Center the cards */
  gap: 40px; /* Add some space between the cards */
}


.container .card {
  flex: 1 1 calc(40% - 20px); /* Adjust the card width and keep some space between them */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Responsive styles for smaller screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .container .card {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.container .card .face.face1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(100px);
  transition: transform 0.8s ease-in-out; /* Ajout de la transition */
  transform: translateY(100px); 
}
```

I tried messing around with the margin instead of using 'gap' but nothing changes.

Comment: maybe the theme add extra css rules to your components, try to open your chrome console and search for some extra stuff like "gap: 3px !important" or something like that. you can try to add an `id` in the upper tag (like `body`) and then prefix all your css rules with it to be sure to have higher priority

Comment: In `.container` you specify `gap: 40px`, but in `.container .card` (the children) you also specify `flex: 1 1 calc(40% - 20px)` and `margin-bottom: 20px`. Is this for a reason? Are you sure this isn't screwing you up? Ideally you'd just rely on the parent's `gap` property to create spacing between cards.